# CS50 speller how to test if it works

Tags: spell-checking, cs50

I think this code loads the dictionary, but how do I check that it works?

'''
 #include 
    #include

```
#include "dictionary.h"


//number of linked lists in hashtable
#define HASH_SIZE 5000
```

#define LENGTH 45

```
char word;

//create node
typedef struct node
{
    char word [LENGTH +1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

//create hashtable as an array of linked lists
node *hashtable[HASH_SIZE];

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
         // malloc a node* for each new word
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        // else if not pointing to NULL, copy word into node
        else
        {
            strcpy(new_node)→ word, word);
            new_node→next = head;
            head = new_node;
        }
    }
    return false;

int hash_function(const char*word)
{
    int sum=0;
    int word_length = strlen(word);

    for(int i=0; i<word-length; i++)
    {
        sum+ = word[i];
    }
    int bucket = sum % HASH_SIZE;
    return bucket;
}
```

'''

I think this code loads the dictionary, but how do I check that it works? 
can you help? Please help me test this code

Comment: Hi Stephen, welcome to stackoverflow. As the `cs50` tag indicates in its description, you should also add the `C` tag. This may in part be why you're not getting any answers. Also please explain in a bit more detail the steps you have taken to run the code, what the output is, and what you expected the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

Conventional CS50 wisdom says the ultimate test for  `load` is `check`! Some pointers:

- Consider signing up for  [CS50's own stack forum](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/). There you will find a community in-the-know about all things CS50.
- Even if this function loads the dictionary, speller will complain "Could not load dictionary" because it always returns `false`. Perhaps review `speller.c` again as recommended in [the spec](https://docs.cs50.net/2019/x/psets/4/speller/hashtable/speller.html).
- It is unlikely that this function "works". `hashtable` is declared and never used. `hash` function is defined and never used.

The first measure of success of `load` is that it doesn't crash. The second is after `size` is completed, and the result shows the correct "WORDS IN DICTIONARY". Next measure is `check` gives the correct results (as compared to say, the files in `keys`).

You will likely find that `debug50` is your best friend for completing this pset. Some final words of wisdom (also from the spec):

> During development, you may find it helpful to provide speller with a
>   dictionary of your own that contains far fewer words, lest you
>   struggle to debug an otherwise enormous structure in memory. In
>   dictionaries/small is one such dictionary.